# Getting values from nested list in separate columns

Tags: r

I hope you can help me with something.
Assume you have the following code:

```
library(gender)


test1 = tibble::tribble(
  ~name1,      ~name2, ~name3, ~name4, ~name5,
  "PETER",      "KLAUS",     NA,     NA,     NA,
  "HEIKE", "ANTONIA",     NA,     NA,     NA,
  "SANDRA", "HEIKO", "HEIKO", "HEIKE", "HEIKE"
)

male_female_row <- list()
for (row in 1:nrow(test1)) {
  x1=gender(as.character(test1[row,]))
  y = table(x1$gender)
  male_female_row[[row]] = y
}
```

than

```
model2 = do.call(rbind.data.frame, male_female_row) ### List to dataframe
```

creates a dataframe.

See for line 1, model2 shows 2,2 but I only have 2 male and 0 women (looking into the list male_female_row). How can I break up the two integers from the list (value) into two separate columns like $male $female?

when I code answer from @Rory:

```
male_values <- map(male_female_row, "male") %>%
  map(~ if_else(is.null(.x), 0, .x)) %>%
  unlist()

female_values <- map(male_female_row, "female") %>%
  map(~ if_else(is.null(.x), 0, .x)) %>%
  unlist()

tibble(male_values, female_values)
```

I get the failure:

```
 `false` must be a double vector, not an integer vector.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general tip, you can use `map` to easily access values from nested lists. The following uses this approach while returning a count of 0 if a female or male value is absent from a list element. This also works if one or more of the values in `male_female_row` is formatted as a character, not a number:

```
# Generate some data
male_female_row <- list(
  list(male = "1"),
  list(male = 2, female = "4"),
  list(male = 3),
  list(male = 5, female = 1),
  list(female = 7)
)

male_values <- map(male_female_row, "male") %>%
  map(~ if_else(is.null(.x), 0, .x)) %>%
  unlist()

female_values <- map(male_female_row, "female") %>%
  map(~ if_else(is.null(.x), 0, .x)) %>%
  unlist()

tibble(male_values, female_values)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  male_values female_values
        <dbl>         <dbl>
1           1             0
2           2             4
3           3             0
4           5             1
5           0             7
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Thats almost what I want, I just want to keep both male and female vectors the same size, so when there is no female I want the element to be 0 in order to compare male and female for each row. Hope I could explain.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've updated my answer to accomplish that - hopefully it's what you had in mind.

Comment: @Max H. Did it solve your problem? Feel free to accept it if so, or let me know if not and I can edit it further

Comment: thanks again for your quick answer. Now I get the failure: `false` must be a double vector, not a character vector. But when I get summary(male_female_row) its all numeric

Comment: @MaxH. That's probably because one (or more) of the values in your nested list is a character, not an integer, so `map_dbl` throws an error. I've edited my answer to fix this. If this still isn't quite right, then editing your question to include your full starting data would help towards finding a solution.

Comment: just updated so you can run the code and test :).